# templateProvider with resolved values in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it true that I can't use resolved values from the parent to state and inject into child state with tempalteProvider? I read some article, people said it can't be done. Resolved values won't be available until it reaches to controller. I need some values to determine which template I need to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're saying is indeed true. But you can circumvent it by using a service. Let's say you have a resolve which fetches it results from a service:

```
'resolve': {
    'myData': ['MyService', function (MyService) {
        return MyService.getData();
    }]
}
```

In that service you can cache/store your results:

```
angular.module('app').factory('MyService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var data;
    return {
        getData: function () {
            // No data yet, fetch it
            if (!data) {
                return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'a.json'}).then(
                    function (result) {
                        // Store for future use
                        data = result.data;
                        // Return data
                        return data;
                    });
            // Data already present
            } else {
                // Return data
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now in your childstate, you can use the service which has the data ready in your templateProvider:

```
'templateProvider': ['$http', 'MyService', function ($http, MyService) {
    var data = MyService.getData();
    return $http.get(data.type + '.html').then(
        function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }
    );
}]
```

Here's a quick 'n dirty example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hUGhmGSowV4XEdXfdS0E?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but what's the reason to cause that?

Comment: According to someone more familiar with the topic: "for this to work, resolve values would have to be resolved synchronously, before templateProvider was executed, which is a performance decrease that many people won't need. This will be difficult to refactor this effectively, because of the number of abstraction boundaries it crosses." See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/330